# Why does my variable change values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9kG8/3/) where I get the value of a div.

In the `$(document).ready(function(){})` section I get the text of the div just fine. When I try to use that value later on in a function, the value changes (unless I add `.innerHTML`). Why does the value of that variable change? In other words, why do I need to add `.innerHTML` when I call that variable later on?

thanks!

```
<div id="my_div">1</div>

// Javascript/JQuery

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var my_div = $("#my_div").text();

        alert(my_div);

        func();
    });


function func(){    
    alert(my_div); // why does the value change here...why???
        alert(my_div.innerHTML); // why do I need ".innerHTML' here???
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value changes because you aren't requesting any specific 'feature' of the div. You're just trying to alert an element...

In the first bit, you have assigned my_div inside the function.
If you move the `var my_div` to outside the function, it becomes a global variable as opposed to a local one.

Edited fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RzuZ2/)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that his original example alerts the div element because `window.my_div` is actually the element by ID.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declare my_div not in the global scope.

You should do like this:

```
var my_div;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    my_div = $("#my_div").text();

    alert(my_div);

    func();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Was a very clear explanation. Accepted chrisbradbury as he was slightly faster than you. thanks again!

Comment: @Mr.Gaga: ok no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because all elements with ID's are properties of the global scope by default.

So basically `my_div` in your `function func()` is the same as calling `window.my_div`.

Try removing `var my_div = $("#my_div").text()` and you'll still be able to use it in `func()`.

This question is related [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var my_div = $("#my_div").text();

    alert(my_div);

    func(my_div);
});


function func(my_div){    
    alert(my_div); // why does the value change here...why???
};
```

You need to pass in reference to my_div.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
function func(){    
    alert(my_div); // why does the value change here...why???
    alert(my_div.innerHTML); // why do I need ".innerHTML' here???
};
```

You get an html element by it's id (`my_div`).
Why ? Because `my_div` ins't declared as global.
That's why when you alert you get an object.

Try to run your code using other name to `my_div`, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var div = $("#my_div").text();

    alert(my_div);

    func();
});


function func(){
    alert(div);
    alert(div.innerHTML);
};
```

You will see that you get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined
```

Comment: Actually ```my_div``` is declared as global ;) see my answer